# C Vector error 'char(*)[]: unknown size' - vector erase iterator outside range

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, vector

**I am sorry that I am new to C. I learned a bit C++ before and I may get confuse between C and C++. But I am trying to write a C program. The only thing I could apply in C++ is vector. This is an exercise for me. Please tell me any mistake I made. Thanks a lot.**

I am working on a program to count the frequency of words in a text file, and output a list of words and the corresponding frequency in the text file. The program aborted with error message:

```
C2036: 'char(*)[]: unknown size'.
```

It points to following lines in the vector file:

```
1475:   _Move_unchecked(_VIPTR(_Where) + 1, this->_Mylast(), _VIPTR(_Where));

1476:   _Destroy(this->_Mylast() - 1, this->_Mylast());

1478:   --this->_Mylast();
```

What I can understand is the message at

```
line 1474: _DEBUG_ERROR("vector erase iterator outside range");
```

But I have no idea about this problem. I do search for similar problem but what I found the solution is specific for the poster's code. Please help. Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <ctype.h>


void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
char *str;
int wordLocation, insertLocation, wordLength;
wordLocation = insertLocation = wordLength = 0;
char *wordCheck;

std::vector<char[]> word;
std::vector<int> frequency;
std::vector<char[]> tempWord;

int tempFreq;

FILE *file;
file = fopen(argv[1], "r");

if (file)
{
    //Read file test
    /*while (fscanf(file, "%s", str)!= EOF)
    {
        printf("s%\n",str);
    }
    */

    while (fscanf(file, "%s",word.end()) != EOF) 
    {
        wordCheck = word[wordLocation];
        wordLength = strlen(wordCheck);

        for (int i = 0; i < wordLength; i++, wordCheck++)
        {
            // Check and remove punctuation
            if (ispunct(*wordCheck))
            {
                *wordCheck = ' ';
            }

            // Check uppercase and transform to lowercase
            if (*wordCheck >= 'A' && *wordCheck <= 'Z')
            {
                *wordCheck = putchar(tolower(*wordCheck));
            }
        }

        // Start to compare word in vector word
        if (int(word.size()) == 1) 
        {
            //only contain 1 input
            frequency[wordLocation] = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= wordLocation; i++)
            {
                // Look for the same word 
                if (word[i] == word[wordLocation])
                {
                    frequency[i]++;
                    word.erase(word.end()-1);
                    break;
                }
                // Add new word at the end
                else if (i == wordLocation && word[i] != word[wordLocation])
                {
                    frequency[wordLocation] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        wordLocation++;
    }
    // Word Sorting
    for (int i = 0; i <= wordLocation; i++) 
    {
        for (int k = 0; k <= wordLocation - 1; k++)
        {
            if (frequency[i] < frequency[i + 1])
            {
                //Swap element

                tempWord.insert(tempWord.begin(),word[i]);
                tempFreq = frequency[i];

                word.erase(word.begin());
                frequency.erase(frequency.begin());
                word.insert(word.begin() + i + 1, tempWord.front());
                frequency.insert(frequency.begin() + i + 1,tempFreq);

                tempWord.pop_back();
            }
        }
    }
    // After sorting, write into the file
    fclose(file);

    remove("output.txt");

    file = fopen("output.txt", "a");
    file = fopen("output.txt", "w");

    for (int i = 0; i <= wordLocation; i++)
    {
        fprintf(file, "%s %d \n", word[i], frequency[i]);
    }
    printf("Create output.txt successed.");
}
else
{
    printf("Read file fail. Please check the input path.\n");
}
```

}

Comment: Distill your program until it is minimal but still crashing.

Comment: This is not **C** but **C++**, different languages.

Comment: It was noticed by Jonathan Leffler that Stack Overflow *actively* suggests to *tag **both** languages* simultaneously. [He posted to meta about it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355331/how-can-we-stop-so-suggesting-both-c-and-c-tags-on-questions).

Comment: If you are trying to write a C program, your first mistake is that you have written a C++ program. You should probably remove the C++ tag, then.

Comment: Better use a C compiler to write a "C program".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> C2036: 'char(*)[]: unknown size'.

Its caused becouse

```
std::vector<char[]> tempWord;
```

Is wrong (You have to specify size or use pointer) and its bad idea to use `char` arrays in `C++`.

Use `std::string` ot `std::array` instead.

```
std::vector<std::string> tempWord;
```

---

`void main` leads to undefined behavior

Entry point must be declared as

```
int main(void)
{
    return 0; // Optimal
}
```

Or with args

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return 0; // Optimal
}
```

---

Also you are using uninitialised pointer and trying to copy data there -> UB

```
char *str;
while (fscanf(file, "%s",str) != EOF)
```

I would recommend you to use automatic array since you are beginner.

```
char str[1024];
```

---

> line 1474: _DEBUG_ERROR("vector erase iterator outside range");

You are indexing an `std::vector` while it hasnt any pushed values -> UB

```
word[wordLocation];
```

First you have to push some strings into the container

```
std::string userInput;
std::cin >> userInput;        // User will enter some string
word.push_back(userInput);    // Push that input into the vector
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am sorry that I am new to C. I learned a bit C++ before and I may get confuse between C and C++. But I am trying to write a C program. The only thing I could apply in C++ is vector. This is an exercise for me. Please tell me any mistake I made. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Everyone was beginner once and made same mistakes as you :-) I would recommend you to do it in parts, not to write a source code with ie 400 lines and then debug it, first try to run scanning from file, if youve got it, then move to next operation and so on

Comment: @FilipKočica: Err, well, not really ... - when I learned C there was no C++ ... ;-)

Comment: I have meant it figuratively :-)

Comment: @FilipKočica Yes I did it step by step. Actually the code is built successfully but it cannot run. So I try to debug. I made some mistake in the modification so I come to this situation :'(. I think I mislead the exercise question: std::vector is allowed to use, but no "using namespace std". Is that not a C program anymore if I include anything to use? Thanks all.

Comment: If you reamove `C` tag it will be OK now, If you remove `C++` tag you have to remove `std::vector`. I would remove `C` tag and write it in `C++`.

Comment: Using std::vector is the suggestion from the question. If I want to store a list of "char array" in C, do you have any suggestion to store it? But the size of the entire "string" depends on the user input from text file. I considered to use struct but I am in doubt that the variable size of input may cause program crash in some specific case. Thanks!

Comment: In `C` you would use pointer to pointer or 2D array, but i would recommend you to modify what i have written in my comment and first make it running this way :-)

Answer (score 0):

C and C++ are different languages. You cannot write a C program and use a bit of C++ in there.

There is no `std::vector` in C. If you want to use `std::vector`, you have to write in C++. If you want to write in C, you cannot use `std::vector`.

Don't use a C++ compiler to compile C programs. This will only add to your confusion.

Comment: Thanks for your reminder. Using std::vector is the suggestion from the question. If I want to store a list of "char array" in C, do you have any suggestion to store it? But the size of the entire "string" depends on the user input from text file. I considered to use struct but I am in doubt that the variable size of input may cause program crash in some specific case.

Comment: If your exercise mentions `using namespace std` and they specifically allow `std::vector`, they are probably trying to teach you C++, not C. If in doubt, ask your TA.

Comment: They do not allow "using namespace std", except "std::vector"

Comment: Look, I have tried hard to explain it but probably not hard enough. Let me try once again before I give up. **If they say something --- anything --- about allowing or not allowing `using namespace std` or `std::vector`, chances are, you are attending a C++ course**. If in doubt, ask your TA.